# Can overloaded methods work with different types without having to cast in c#?

Tags: c#

I have 3 simple classes for this example:

```
 public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class E : User
{
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
}
public class F : User
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a few simple Print methods that I'm overloading to take a specific type. Don't mind response write, it's only for displaying the goal which is to use properties on that type that are not in the base.

```
public void Print(E e)
{
    Response.Write(e.FirstName);
}

public void Print(F f)
{
    Response.Write(f.LastName);
}
```

I'm curious about how I can get these instructions to work without having to cast the type? In total, I have 4 seperate `User`s. Each goes through the same process. I'd love to have the code once, not 4 times. This code below will not compile because `LastName` is not on the `User` object.

```
User u = UserFactory.Get("f");
Print(u);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't implement a Print method on your user? The subclasses could then override it appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should implement like this instead.

```
void Main()
{
User u = UserFactory.Get("f");
u.Print();
}


public class User
{
public string FirstName { get; set; }

public virtual void Print()
{
    Response.Write(this.FirstName);
}
}

public class E : User
{
public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

public override void Print()
{
    Response.Write(this.FirstName);
}
}
public class F : User
{
public string LastName { get; set; }

public override void Print()
{
    Response.Write(this.LastName);
}
}
```

Comment: It could be said this is against SOLID principals and Print is not an function of a User. However you could do a similar thing with an extension method.

Comment: How is it against solid principles?  It appears to be that print is only used for Users objects so it belongs in User.

Comment: It appears to me Print uses a Response object, whatever that is, furthermore presumably it prints something, how and to what is not a concern of a user.

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice to keep the print logic separate from the entity itself (Separation of Concerns).  I would create an `IPrintable` interface:

```
public interface IPrintable
{
    string Data { get; }
}
```

... and then implement that on the `User` class (making it `abstract` if you can)

```
public abstract class User : IPrintable
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public abstract string Data { get; }
}
```

Each subclass can then implement the `Data` getter

```
public class E : User
{
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }
    public override string Data { get { return MiddleInitial; } }
}

public class F : User
{
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public override string Data { get { return LastName; } }
}
```

... and whatever you use to print can just accept an `IPrintable` object

```
public void Print(IPrintable entity)
{
    Response.Write(entity.Data);
}
```

This has a number of advantages.  Firstly, if you ever want to print any other kind of object (other than a `User` object) you could just have that object implement `IPrintable`.  Nothing would need to change in your `Print` method.

Another advantage is that your `Print` method is now easily unit testable.  You can simply pass in a mock `IPrintable` object when testing.  Your unit test isn't dependent on any concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I would make UserFactory return the correct type:

```
F f = UserFactory.GetF();
```

or:

```
F f;
UserFactory.Get<F>(out f);
```

Comment: The factory would return `new F()` or `new E()` depending on the input string. The variable is still declared as `User`.

Comment: I understand, I am saying I would change the factory by adding overloads to get a F or E explicitly which also prevents an invalid string being supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        virtual public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(FirstName);
        }
    }

    public class E : User
    {
        public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

        override public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MiddleInitial);
        }
    }
    public class F : User
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        override public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(LastName);
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var userArray = new User[3];

            userArray[0] = new User { FirstName = "John" };
            userArray[1] = new F { LastName = "Doe" };
            userArray[2] = new E { MiddleInitial = "K" };

            PrintUsers(userArray);
        }

        private static void PrintUsers(User[] userArray)
        {
            foreach (var user in userArray)
            {
                user.Print();
            }
        }
    }
```

This uses method overriding so that each call automatically selects the appropriate method.

Comment: it doesn't use overloading, it uses overriding